# Output results of a bash shell script in columns and rows

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am working on a homework assignment that checks user permissions of all files in a directory. I would like to output all of the filenames in one column and the permissions in one or multiple columns. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
bold=$(tput bold)
normal=$(tput sgr0)
red=`tput setaf 1`
reset=`tput sgr0`
DIR1=$1
cd $1
num=0
for file in *; do
echo ${bold}$file${normal}
if [ -r $file ] 
   then    
      echo ${red}"r"${reset} ;
fi    
if [ -w $file ]
   then       
      echo ${red}"w"${reset};
fi    
if [ -x $file ]
   then       
     echo ${red}"x"${reset};
fi
# ls -l $file | awk '{print $1 }
#ls -1 $file | awk '{print $1 }
(( num+=1 ))
# echo $num
done

echo
echo

if  [ $1 ]
then
echo $num files in specified directory '('`pwd`')'
else
echo $num files in directory '('`pwd`')'
echo

fi
echo
echo
```

Comment: `printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" a b c`

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We expect you to do the work of generating the smallest possible code that demonstrates your problem (and that someone can extend, modify, or refer to to reproduce that problem or reuse in their answer), **not** to dump your larger program here in the question; see the documentation on building a [mcve].

Comment: Was it not clear? I appreciate the constructive feedback, but it isn't the feedback I was looking for. I was looking for how to output columns from the above code. I can clarify if you desire

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to output all of the filenames in one column and the permissions in one or multiple columns.

Something like this might do it:

```
stat -c "%A %n" *
```

Change the output of `stat` if you prefer the filename first:

```
stat -c "%n %A" *
```

And if you want the output as a table you can use the `column` command:

```
stat -c "%n:%A" * | column -t -s ':'
```

But that is not a good solution if you have `:` in your paths, which you can change for any other character.

Of course you can use the same logic in a loop:

```
#!/bin/bash               

red=$(tput setaf 1)       
bold=$(tput bold)         
reset=$(tput sgr0)        

for file in "${1:-"${PWD}"}"/*; do                                                                       

    perm=$(stat -c %A "${file}")                  
    echo "${bold}${file}${reset}:${red}${perm:1:3}${reset}"                                              

done | column -t -s ":"
```